# java: reduce vs anyMatch vs contains

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
 List<Boolean> results = new ArrayList<>();
 results.add(true);
 results.add(true);
 results.add(true);
 results.add(false);

 if (results.contains(false)) {
     System.out.println(false);
 } else {
     System.out.println(true);
 }

 System.out.println(results.stream().reduce((a, b) -> a && b).get());
 //System.out.println(!results.stream().anyMatch(a -> a == false));
 System.out.println(!results.stream().anyMatch(a -> !a));
```

OUTPUT:
false
false
false

FYI, the results are a result of a map+collect op

```
List<Job> jobs;
List<Boolean> results = job.stream().map(j -> j.ready()).collect(Collector.toList())
```

If I choose either reduce or anyMatch, I don't have to collect the results from map operation.

From results which is a list of boolean, I just want to return false if there is at least one false.

I can do it via reduce or anyMatch. I kinda don't like Optional from reduce, and I kinda don't like that I have to negate anyMatch

Are there any pros/cons for using either?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that the only reason you are collecting the booleans into the list is so you can check if some are `false`:

> If I choose either reduce or anyMatch, I don't have to collect the results from map operation  [...]  I just want to return false if there is at least one false.

If this is the case, then you definitely should consider the straightforward stream-based approach:

```
return jobs.stream().allMatch(Job::ready);
```

Answer (score 2):

You ask pros/cons. `Contains` is the fastest and simplest. `Reduce` is the most cumbersome/complicated here. But your task is very simple, so does it really matter? Maybe the better key to select which approach to use would be: "Which one is better readable, understandable and maintainable?" This clean-code approach is usually more important in practical software development than hunting microseconds in runtime or number of lines in source code. But then again I would say `contains` is the best here.

```
System.out.println(!results.contains(false));
```

Then your `anyMatch(a -> !a)` is effectively the same as `contains` and I would definitely prefer it over `reduce` for this concrete task. But again, real difference is very small and I would more concern the readability and understandability for a future maintainer of this software.

Comment: thank you for your input. does my edit changes your view on the answer? my original code is the "contain" approach but i recieved comments that i should be doing map-reduce or map-anymatch

Comment: streams are the slowest way to process anything, unless you have 1000's of elements and a parallel stream is used; there's quite a lot going on under the hood. Plus `contains()` is short, simple to code and read, and the fastest.

Comment: @Bohemian yeah hence i chose contains but i m the new guy on the team so dont want to push back on their suggestions. ill probably go with anyMatch then

Comment: @Bohemian why are streams suggested then if they are the slowest way to process things?

Comment: @Doc who says they are “suggested”? They’re a syntactic option that can make parallel code easier to write, and capture some common paradigms in a consistent way. But they are in the general case, slower than plain old loops.

Comment: @Bohemian I do not agree that “streams are the slowest way to process anything”. There are scenarios where a Stream can perform faster than a conventional loop, due to the different way of interfacing with the collection. However, for operations where the collection itself offers a genuine way of doing it, that way should always be preferred, as it is not only potentially more efficient, but usually also much simpler. The worst examples of Stream overuse are those streaming over a `Set` or `Map` to find a matching key, whereas both sources offer a better-than-linear lookup operation.

Comment: @holger I’m not saying “streams are bad”. The code can be much cleaner using the new syntax. However, for heavy processing the overheads of using a stream over plain loops can make the benefits of cleaner looking code not worth the extra processing expense that goes on under the hood (IMHO).

Comment: @Bohemian it’s not about “good” or “bad”; it’s simply not correct that Streams are always slower. The maintenance of an `Iterator` used by a conventional loop can be more costly that the encapsulation of the per-element operation into a `Consumer`.

Comment: @holger I didn’t say Streams are always slower. I said in the general (small collection size, simple operation) case, they are slower, due to the overhead of creating and managing the stream, plus the all the extra stackframes created (loops don’t have any).

Comment: @Bohemian you said “*streams are the slowest way to process anything, unless you have 1000's of elements and a parallel stream is used*”, which reads like sequential streams were always slower. Unless you’re limiting your statement to plain arrays, loops *do* have additional stackframes, as they are calling into the `Iterator` methods, even if the neat for-each syntax allows to hide it from the source code. In either case, the JIT’s inlining capabilities play an important role, but as said, maintaining the *state* of an iterator can be more costly than the internal iteration used by a stream.

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.out.println(results.stream().reduce((a, b) -> a && b).get());
```

This will always return false, as the list(`results`) has at-least 1 `false`.

**&&** will always check for both value to be true to pass it as `true`.

```
 System.out.println(!results.stream().anyMatch(a -> !a));
```

Stream `anyMatch(Predicate predicate)` returns whether any elements of this stream(**results**) match the provided **predicate**`(a -> !a)`. As you are doing `!results` so the result will come-out to be false at last after initial **true**.

Comment: i dont know if you are correct on anyMatch, it will return false if there was match (true) for the predicate which is that an element is false